# How to add and remove class of one element while hovering over another element via Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, angularjs-scope

I'd like to add a class to an `<li>` when it's child `<a>` gets hovered over but I can't seem to get it to work. What is happening is that no matter what `<a>` element is hovered over, only the first `<li>` gets affected so I need to be able to target only the parent `<li>` of the `<a>` that is currently being hovered over.

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/faGTg/39/

and here is the code:

**Controller** (Javascript)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller("Ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.addClass = function(){
        angular.element(document.querySelector('.li-hover')).addClass('hovering');
    }
    $scope.removeClass = function(){
        angular.element(document.querySelector('.li-hover')).removeClass('hovering');
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <ul>
            <li class="li-hover" >
                <a href="" ng-mouseover="addClass()" ng-mouseleave="removeClass()">
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="li-hover" >
                <a href="" ng-mouseover="addClass()" ng-mouseleave="removeClass()">
                  <span>About</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="li-hover" >
                <a href="" ng-mouseover="addClass()" ng-mouseleave="removeClass()">
                  <span>Contact</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hovering {
    background-color: pink;
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
li {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 2em;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #aaa;
    background: #ccc;
}
a { 
    background: white;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate scope using a repeater, and change a property of the repeated item:

```
myApp.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {
      href: '',
      title: 'Home',
    },
    {
      href: '',
      title: 'About',
    },
    {
      href: '',
      title: 'Contact',
    }
  ];
});
```

Then, you can store a over property on `item`, and use it to change class:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{hovering: item.over}">
    <a ng-href="{{item.href}}" title="{{item.title}}" ng-mouseover="item.over=true" ng-mouseleave="item.over=false">
      <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/faGTg/41/

Or you can use a simple var for that now, because the `ng-repeat` directive isolates each item in a new scope:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{hovering: over}">
    <a ng-href="{{item.href}}" title="{{item.title}}" ng-mouseover="over=true" ng-mouseleave="over=false">
      <span>{{item.title}}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I think this is better, because styling on hovering is a view concern. Although the solution above sets a `hover` property in the current scope, the controller does not need to be concerned about this.

http://jsfiddle.net/33ypvx3g/

Comment: I would just keep the second option because it is simpler

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any js or jQuery code for that, you can accomplish this with the css `:hover` selector. Add this to your css:

```
li:hover {
   background-color: pink;
   border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

Here is the working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/faGTg/40/

Comment: You misunderstand. Some of my `<li>` elements will not contain `<a>` elements. I need to apply classes only to `<li>`s whose child `<a>`s are currently being hovered over.